# How to update MySQL datetime field when a link is viewed

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a site for my wife. She uploads pdf documents to it and then shares those documents with her boss. I have the site uploading the documents to Amazons S3, and a MySQL DB handling the paths, user passwords, and usernames, etc...

My wife wants to know when her boss views one of the documents she posts.

The only way I can think of is rather than sending the viewer to their document, send them to a php page with `$_POST` data. have that page do the UPDATE to MySQL then forward the viewer on to their requested document.

This seems a little much. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Maybe Amazon S3 saves the date a file was last viewed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use GET over POST so you can send the document's link via e-mail. Besides that there is no easier way to do that.

For example if you use a web analytics tool you also need a PHP script with a SELECT. In this case I think it's the same effort if you implement the analytics tool or do a second SQL query for the UPDATE ;)

Btw it is not that much work. Here is a quick and (very, very) dirty example. It is not tested but I only wanted to show you that you can do it with about 15 lines of code ;) I assumed a table "documents" with id, url and last_access and a PHP script which is sent to the boss with an ID parameter: doc.php?id=1

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$select_sql = "SELECT `url` FROM `documents` WHERE `id` = " . $id . ";";
$result = mysql_query($select_sql);

if (!$result) {
  die(mysql_error());
}

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if ($row) {
  $update_sql = "UPDATE `documents` SET `last_access` = NOW() WHERE `id` = " . $id . ";";
  mysql_query($update_sql);
  header('Location: ' . $row[url]);
} else {
  echo 'Not Found';
}
```

Comment: Other than adding security and sanitation thats it... Simpler than what I was doing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add some analytics tool, which actually does similar stuff. I.e. Link a Google Analytics with the page and track the event of the pdf link click.

Answer (score -4):

The whole thing seems a little over the top. Using a service like Google Drive could have saved you a lot of headache.

If you need the view notify feature, yes, a PHP file to server the actual PDF file, which also updates a database, or sends an email is the way to go. No need to use POST though.

Alternatively, check if Amazon keeps records of when files were viewed.

Comment: It would save some headache, but not the learning experience :)

Comment: Google drive (free version) has a limit of like 15 gb. My wife has terabytes of Documents to post.